# Passing variable in python request URL not working

Tags: python, json, variables, python-requests

```
def get_prod():
    name = input('Search Query:\n')
    params = {
    'page': '1',
    'perPage': '20',
    'query': name,
}
    response = requests.get('https:///api/public/search', params=params, headers=headers)
    response = response.json()
    id = response['results'][0]['id']
    print(id)
    prod_data = requests.get('https:///api/public/products/{id}', headers=headers)
    print(prod_data.text)

get_prod()
```

from the public API Search I am returning a valid ID but when the `prod_data` get request returns the error `{"message":"Couldn't find Product with 'id'={id} [WHERE \"products\".\"deleted_at\" IS NULL]"}` implying to me that it's not using that variable I can print. When I put a standard finite ID the request works but I'm sure why this won't

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the variable value is not getting printed. Unless I'm missing something.

You need a `f` before the string if you're going with this method; f-strings.

```
prod_data = requests.get(f'https:///api/public/products/{id}', headers=headers)
```

These might help: https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/string_formatting.html

Comment: yep works... such a stupid error on my part smh